# conversion from string to TimeStamp data type

Tags: java, timestamp

i want to convert this : 17:26:54 to a TimeStamp data type. I need to enter it into a database. How do i do this?
i have the data in a string variable
i'm using java.
I'm extracting this data from another source and i need to push it into a databse, in which the column for time stamp is defined to be of the type TimeStamp. I'm using JDBC to push data from the java program to MySQL.
So i need a solution to convert the string : 17:26:54 to the timeStamp datatype so that it can be entered into the database without throwing an sql exception error.

edit: I do not need the date part of the timeStamp because i do not use it anywhere in my computations, and neither do I have the option of extracting it from the source which is generating the time information.

Comment: what about date? for what database?

Comment: Do you know anything about JDBC?

Comment: i dont need the data.. Im extracting this data from another source. I just need to push it into a MySQL database, where i have defined the column to be of "timestamp" datatype.. so i just need to convert it to an acceptable format in java to be able to push successfully into MySQL using JDBC

Comment: yes, @ElliottFrisch, im using it to push data into MySQL from java

Comment: So, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Generally a timestamp datatype includes a date, so what do you want to set that to? Java epoch, today, something else...

Comment: need to know the right datatype so that when i push to sql it doesnt throw an error. because the time i have is in string format and the database column type is "timestamp"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch null maybe? doesnt matter to me because i dont need date

Comment: @user3799135: It sounds like you don't want a timestamp field then; you want a time field. A timestamp is inherently a point in time, not a time of day. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: @user3799135 Please edit your question when supplying additional information, rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PreparedStatement#setTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29) or [PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) to insert `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

To convert String to Date or Timestamp use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Sample code:

```
 String time="12/07/2014 17:26:54";

 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 Date date=format.parse(time);
```

If you try below sample code then default date will be Jan 1, 1970

```
 String time="17:26:54";

 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 Date date=format.parse(time);
```

How to convert Java date to SQL date?

```
 java.util.Date javaDate=new java.util.Date();
 java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());
```

---

> How to insert it into database timestamp data type?

Sample code:

```
String time="17:26:54";

SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date=format.parse(time);

...

PreparedStatement stmt = conn
        .prepareStatement("insert into test(message,time) values(?,?)");
stmt.setString(1, "This is message");
stmt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Find [complete sample code](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

Comment: If the issue is resolved the close the thread by accepting the desired answer. [visit](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class to convert string to a `java.util.Date` instance.

[**java.sql.Timestamp**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) can be constructed with long date representation, which can be get from `java.util.Date` class instance via `getTime()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments

> doesnt matter to me because i dont need date

Make it a colum of [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) type. Then per the [getting started with JDBC guide](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html),

> java.sql.Time for SQL TIME information. The year, month, and day fields of the java.util.Date base class are set to 1970, January, and 1. This is the "zero" date in the Java epoch.

The [Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#Time%28long%29) constructor,

```
long millis = (hour * 3600 * 1000) + (minutes * 60 * 1000) + (seconds * 1000);
java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(millis);
```

Comment: It's [deprecated cosntrutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#Time%28int,%20int,%20int%29) and you will never suggest anyone to use it.

Comment: thanks this helps :) i'll do that in my database. but in order to write into my database from java, i need a compatible value (i cannot insert a string type into time type) So i need to convert 17:26:54 into time datatype.. how do i do that

Comment: Use setDate and pass it a Time object, convert to hours minutes and seconds and use my method above.